# Dragging from Outlook to Chrome moves email to Deleted folder

Tags: google-chrome, outlook, drag-and-drop

Recently, I noticed that the drag and drop function was added back so that you could successfully drag an email from your Microsoft Outlook inbox to a web app's file upload. The issue is that once the file has been dragged to the web app, the email is moved to the Deleted folder in Outlook. Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: Have you tested that behavior in other browsers as well?

Comment: Other browsers seem to work fine. I checked Edge and we don't use any others within the firm.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be solved by the web developper.
You can go to the following web page to see exemples with the different behaviors (copy, move, link) when we do a drag and drop in a browser:
https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/epQPNP

Put the following line into 'dragenter', 'dragover' and 'drop' event handler :
e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";

My code to solve the issue:

```
$('#myDropArea').on({
  'dragenter': function (e) {            
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).addClass('draginprogress');
    $(this).find('.DragText').css({ 'z-index': '1000' }).show()

  },
  'dragover': function (e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  },
  'dragleave': function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();            
    $(this).removeClass('draginprogress');
    $(this).find('.DragText').hide();
  },
  'drop': function (e) {
    var dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    $(this).removeClass('draginprogress');
    $(this).find('.DragText').hide()
    if (dataTransfer && dataTransfer.files.length) {
      e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      //DO DROP action
    }
  }
});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are doing `move` instead of `copy`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I tried adding some JavaScript code to our web app to adjust for this but I had no luck. `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';`

Comment: What do you do in your drop handler? Do you set effectAllowed?